# Predict action in future based on data

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, prediction

I have the following data:

```
{
 ["17.05.2017 17:34", 1],
 ["16.05.2017 17:12", 1],
 ["15.05.2017 17:22", 1],
 ["14.05.2017 17:56", 1],
 ["13.05.2017 17:32", 1],
 ["12.05.2017 17:39", 1],
}
```

what would be the easiest way to predict on what time today (18.05.2017) a 1 would occour?
(Not just calculating the average - what should be done if the data points were a little bit more messy with gaps? What to do if even more parameters come into this?)

Would it be possible to train something like tensorflow for this?

thanks in advance,
markus

Answer (score 1):

Neural networks generally work good with large amount of data, for your data you can use a basic classification algorithm like logistic regression or Decision tree by providing date as data and `1 or 0` to predict as label. I suppose from your questions you only have a basic understanding of machine-learning, if so go check out some tutorials or do a  course from [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/) almost all the classification problems deal with data like the one you are asking.